# i am running a program to send a picture over two sockets and i have got no errors but the program gets stuck

Tags: python, sockets, opencv

I created a server and a client in python so I could send an image across two sockets but when I run the client it receives the data but once it reaches the end of the file it gets stuck. It raises no error and doesn't crash the terminal is just there stuck.

I have tried changing the code a bit to no avail. I am still a beginner.

**client.py**

```
import socket
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import pickle

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',5000))

host_ip = ('127.0.0.1',400)

client_socket.connect(host_ip)

serialized_img = b""
while True:
    packet = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not packet :
        break
    serialized_img += packet


image = pickle.loads(serialized_img)
cv2.imshow("a",image)
```

**server.py**

```
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pickle

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',400))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret,img = cap.read()

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

serialized_img = pickle.dumps(img)
print(serialized_img)
while ret:
   try:
     server_socket.listen()

     client_socket,client_address =  server_socket.accept()

     print(client_address)

     client_socket.sendall(serialized_img)
   except socket.timeout :
        print("time out")


server_socket.close()
```

I want the client side to be able to show the image.

Comment: use `print()` to display information in different moments to see which part of code makes problem. Maybe it wait for more data.

Comment: you could close `client_socket` in server to inform client that it end of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close `client_socket` in server to inform client that it end of data.

```
client_socket.sendall(serialized_img)
client_socket.close()
```

In client you have to wait for key to keep window opened.

```
cv2.imshow("a", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Server:

```
import socket
import cv2
import pickle

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4000))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, img = cap.read()
cap.release()

cv2.imshow("server", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

serialized_img = pickle.dumps(img)

while ret:
    try:
        server_socket.listen()

        client_socket,client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print(client_address)

        client_socket.sendall(serialized_img)
        client_socket.close()
        print('closed')

    except socket.timeout :
        print("time out")

server_socket.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import cv2 
import pickle

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4000))

serialized_img = b""

while True:
    packet = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not packet :
        break
    serialized_img += packet

image = pickle.loads(serialized_img)

cv2.imshow("client", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

If you want to send live video then server would have to run separate thread with camera or with `while ret`. And every client_socket run in separate thread in `while True` loop. Problem is how to inform client where is end of one frame and beginning of next frame. You couldn't use `close()` for this.

---

**EDIT:** this code streams images from camera so client can see on live - with small delay.

It sends image's size before image so client know how many bytes to receive to get full image. Serialized integer has always 8 bytes so I always receive 8 bytes before image.

I use `cv2.waitKey(10)` in client to check button not only to close window but it didn't display image without this. Maybe window has to receive events from system to work correctly (and refresh window) like in others modules - ie. PyGame - and `waitKey()` is checking events.

Server:

```
import socket
import cv2
import pickle

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4000))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    try:
        server_socket.listen()

        print('waiting ...')
        client_socket,client_address =  server_socket.accept()
        print(client_address)

        while True:
            try:
                ret, img = cap.read()

                serialized_img = pickle.dumps(img)
                print('serialized_len:', len(serialized_img))

                serialized_len = pickle.dumps(len(serialized_img))
                #print('len(serialized_len):', len(serialized_len)) # always length 8

                client_socket.sendall(serialized_len) # always length 8
                client_socket.sendall(serialized_img)
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
                # exit loop when errro, ie. when client close connection
                break 

        client_socket.close()
        print('closed')

    except socket.timeout:
        print('time out')

cap.release()
server_socket.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import cv2 
import pickle

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4000))

cv2.namedWindow('client')

while True:
    serialized_image = b""

    serialized_len = client_socket.recv(8) # always length 8
    length = pickle.loads(serialized_len) 
    #print('length:', length)

    while length > 0:
        if length < 1024:
            packet = client_socket.recv(length)
        else:
            packet = client_socket.recv(1024)

        if not packet:
            print('error: no data')
            break

        serialized_image += packet
        length -= len(packet)

    #print('received:', len(serialized_image))

    image = pickle.loads(serialized_image)
    cv2.imshow('client', image)

    # it need it to display image (maybe it has to receive events from system)
    # it `waitKey` waits 10ms so it doesn't block loop
    key = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0XFF
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```